# Only See Camera View in Viewport and Black Out Background?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, camera

So I saw people have the camera only show the rendered image in the viewport with the entire background blacked out.

How do I do that? I tried ctrl + b but it just did nothing but make the camera outline have different cursors to drag it

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your camera and in *Object Data > Viewport Display*, increase the *Passepartout* value up to 1:

[image]